# WKBReadingError: Could not create geometry because of errors while reading input

Tags: python, postgis, wkb

I want to upload data with postgis using an sql query. See below the code

```
df = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_postgis('select ST_ASTEXT(point_sm) as geom from df.df' , con=engine, geom_col='geom')
```

I get this error:

> ParseException: Invalid HEX char
>
> WKBReadingError: Could not create geometry because of errors while reading input.

I haven't tried much to be honest. I am new to this and couldn't figure out where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are requesting a text but the function expects a geometry expressed in WKB.

Try changing the query to

```
select point_sm as geom from df.df
```